# Is it possible to delete a comment from a YouTube video after all comments have been disabled?

Tags: youtube, comments

Is it possible to delete a comment from a video's comment history after all comments for that video have been disabled?

Alternatively, is comment history inherently deleted for a video which has disabled them? Or may they become re-enabled at any time?

Comment: did you check https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history ?